# PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in the cursor SQL developer

Tags: oracle

```
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbdrop;
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbcreate;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
   ORDER_ID     ORDERS.ODID%TYPE;
   COMPANY_NAME ORDERS.CNAME%TYPE;
   ORDER_DATE   ORDERS.ODATE%TYPE;
   CURSOR ord_cursor IS 
        SELECT ODID, CNAME, ODATE
            FROM ORDERS
            WHERE ODER_DATE< CURDATE()
            LIMIT 5;
BEGIN
   OPEN ord_cursor;
   LOOP
     FETCH ord_cursor into ORDER_ID, COMPANY_NAME, ORDER_DATE;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('           ');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODER ID: '|| TO_CHAR(Order_Id));
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'ODER DATE: ' || ORDER_DATE );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COMPANY NAME: '||  COMPANY_NAME );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '------------');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '------------');
     IF emp_cursor%NOTFOUND THEN 
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE ord_cursor;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
```

And the error shows:
    Error report -
    ORA-06550: line 9, column 13:
    PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    ORA-06550: line 6, column 9:
    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:

Comment: Pls remove the sql-server tag

Comment: Sorry for tagging SQL Server mistaken

Comment: why you have two different cursors? or is it typo? rename cursor `emp_cursor` to `ord_cursor`

Comment: yeah, i've changed it, but the problem is still there

Comment: `CURDATE()` and `LIMIT` clauses within the query do not exist in Oracle DB, replace with `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` and `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY` respectively. `FETCH` clause works provided your DB version is 12c+

Comment: Thank you Barnaros!! I've done as your comment, but there is still errors shows :ORA-06550: line 9, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FETCH" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action: